# one more question with cardinality: $(\{1,2,3\}^{\mathbb{N}} - \{1,2\}^{\mathbb{N}})\cap\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}).$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How can I calculate the cardinality of
$$\left(\{1,2,3\}^{\mathbb{N}} - \{1,2\}^{\mathbb{N}}\right)\cap\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}).$$
where $A^B$ is the set of all functions $f\colon B\to A$.

thanks

Comment: Nir, if you write the question in Hebrew I will translate it properly, and you could learn the names of the terms and make your future questions clearer.

Comment: היי אסף, 
למעשה זה ממש כך, העתקתי את הסימנים מהשאלה. הפונקציות מ-N ל -  {1,2,3} פחות הפונקציות מ -N ל- {1,2} חיתוך עם קבוצת החזקה של NXN

Comment: Nir, it's not the notation but the terminology.

Comment: תודה, אקח לתשומת ליבי.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, you certainly know that you have at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements in your difference.

So to show that $\{1,2,3\}^{\mathbb{N}} - \{1,2\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ has cardinality exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$, it is enough to produce $2^{\aleph_0}$ functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$ whose image is not contained in $\{1,2\}$.

Now, hopefully you agree that there are just as many functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1,2\}$ as there are from $\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$ to $\{1,2\}$? Now, take a function from $\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$ to $\{1,2\}$, and extend it to all of $\mathbb{N}$ in such a way that you *guarantee* the image includes $3$. That will produce at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ functions in $\{1,2,3\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ that are not in $\{1,2\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Ok, so ill do it that way,
for each function from N to {1,2} I'll return a function that 
For n=0 returns 3, and for n>0 you'll get F(n-1), afcourse this is an injective function that covers {1,2,3} and the cardinality is א.

Comment: @Nir: To conclude something about cardinality, you'll have to show that this correspondence is injective (different functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1,2\}$ yield different functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$ whose image includes $3$) (easy); that will not show the cardinality of the set you want is *exactly* $2^{\aleph_0}$, it will show it is **at least** that.

Answer (score 2):

So you have all the functions from $\mathbb{N} \to \{1,2,3\}$ that are not in $\mathbb{N} \to \{1,2\}$?  Each of these functions is a subset of P($\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$), so that part is not important.  Hint: you just need one 3 in the image to take it out of $\mathbb{N} \to \{1,2\}$

Comment: ok, so from one side I have this group, which it's power is less than all the functions from N to {1,2,3} on the other side I can argue that the functions from N to {1,2} has less power than our set, I just can't think of a way to do that.. I got a little mess with that. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: $|3^{\mathbb{N}}|=|2^{\mathbb{N}}|$, but you were asking about $3^{\mathbb{N}} \setminus 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is "most of" $3^{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: @Nir Avnon: Don't say "group"; that means something else. And the usual terminology in English is "cardinality", not "power" (the "power of a set" is likely to be confused with the set of all subsets of the set, which is called the power set).